# Is a body in uniform circular motion in equilibrium?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, equilibrium

I know this question has been asked a myriad different times, but nowhere can I seem to find a definitive, final resolution to it.

Is a body in uniform circular motion in equilibrium?

Comment: Obviously no! Where is the problem? Otherwise every body, no matter its motion in an inertial reference frame, is in equilibrium: it would be sufficient to stay in a reference frame at rest with it.

Comment: I would have been of the same opinion, had not the textbook prescribed by my curriculum explicitly stated that a body in UCM is in dynamic equilibrium (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force#Equilibrium) about 4 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for some of the keywords, it seems like this issue of an object in uniform circular motion being in "dynamical equilibrium" arose from a book (or multiple books using the same original source) for ICSE prep.  See, the third example in this text segment posted on [this site](https://askfilo.com/user-question-answers-science/2-dynamic-equilibrium-when-a-body-remains-in-the-same-state-35343030343334)

[image: original section of book]

But a similar book seems to have eliminated reference to the circular motion examples now.  See [pdf linked here](https://pdfcoffee.com/qdownload/force-work-energy-and-power-physics-pdf-free.html) with this updated section:

[image: updated section of textbook]

Anyway, as others have noted, there is no good definition of "dynamical equilibrium" that can include an object in uniform circular motion. An object in equilibrium experiences zero net force (and thus, by Newton II, has zero acceleration).  An object in circular motion has, by definition, an acceleration.

One could say that an object in "dynamical equilibrium" is one for which the sum of the forces is zero but it moves with constant velocity with respect to its surroundings.  But that's really true for any object in equilibrium, depending on your definition of surroundings and your choice of inertial frame.

It could be that this arose because some introduce a centrifugal force to explain objects in circular motion, essentially moving $m\vec{a}$ over to the other side of Newton's Second Law.  But that is not a good way to think of it.

Answer (score 0):

A body is said to be in a state of equilibrium if all the forces acting on the body are balanced.
Note that the frame of reference for observing the body in motion should be an inertial frame.
A body in uniform circular motion has three forces acting on it (considering a simple case in which there is no resistive forces).
Those are the Weight, the Normal, and the centripetal force.
If you make a free body diagram you find that the centripetal force always remains untouched in UCM.

Thus, it is not in equilibrium.

And it all makes sense too, if there is no force acting on the body then how is the body continuously changing its direction of motion??
It should have flung off.
(Centrifugal force is a pseudo force and is meant to only be taken into consideration in a non-inertial frame)

I hope that helps

Comment: Some statements here are not correct, e.g., "has three forces acting on it", and "centripetal force".  The "centripetal force" is not a type of force it is just a (sometimes) convenient and (always) confusing way to describe the forces causing centripetal acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Equilibrium means that the net force on the body on any chosen axis is zero. A body in uniform circular motion has constant *magnitude* of velocity, but its *direction* is continuously changing (always tangential to the circle) and thus there is an acceleration. For non zero acceleration (centripetal in this case), there has to be some unbalanced force in the same direction as acceleration. Which means that, the object is not in equilibrium.
However, a particle travelling in a straight line unidirectionally with constant magnitude of velocity can be said to be in equilibrium since the magnitude *and* the direction of its velocity are constant.

Comment: It's been stated in my textbook: "when a body remains in the same state of rotational motion under the influence of several forces, it is said to be in dynamic equilibrium." It then proceeds to imply that a body in uniform circular motion is in dynamic equilibrium. Is this wrong?

Comment: Definitely wrong. An example of dynamic equilibrium is the body travelling unidirectionally (quoting from my answer), not circular motion.